# Oracle's GV$SQL_MONITOR - Uniquely identify execution of a SQL statement

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I'm playing around with the data from `GV$SQL_MONITOR` and I found something that I don't understand. The [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-79E97A84-9C27-4A5E-AC0D-C12CB3E748E6.htm#REFRN30479) says that `SQL_EXEC_START`, `SQL_ID`, and `SQL_EXEC_ID` combine to "*uniquely identify one execution of the SQL statement*". However, I see the below data in the table. Many records have the same `SQL_EXEC_START`, `SQL_ID`, and `SQL_EXEC_ID`, but a unique SID.

Does anyone here have insight into why the documentation and my observations contradict each other?

Possibly relevant: I observed that all of these queries finish at the same time.

```
SQL_EXEC_START        SQL_ID        SID SQL_EXEC_ID ELAPSED_TIME STATUS              LAST_REFRESH_TIME   
--------------------- ------------- --- ----------- ------------ ------------------- ---------------------
2017-09-20 14:27:56   gncss37ygprra 196    16777218      1847766 EXECUTING           2017-09-20 14:27:58   
2017-09-20 14:27:56   gncss37ygprra 3148    16777218       498598 EXECUTING           2017-09-20 14:28:00   
2017-09-20 14:27:56   gncss37ygprra 3329    16777218        96863 EXECUTING           2017-09-20 14:28:00   
2017-09-20 14:27:56   gncss37ygprra 480    16777218      1849199 EXECUTING           2017-09-20 14:27:58   
2017-09-20 14:27:56   gncss37ygprra 3727    16777218      1848618 EXECUTING           2017-09-20 14:27:58   
2017-09-20 14:27:56   gncss37ygprra 498    16777218       513823 EXECUTING           2017-09-20 14:28:00   
2017-09-20 14:27:56   gncss37ygprra 2578    16777218      1955707 EXECUTING           2017-09-20 14:28:00   
2017-09-20 14:27:56   gncss37ygprra 3541    16777218      1848522 EXECUTING           2017-09-20 14:27:58
```

Comment: select SQL_EXEC_START start_tm, sid, SQL_ID, max(last_refresh_time) end_tm from gv$sql_monitor ... should help. I hazard a guess that this seems a PX SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Let's create the below function so we can have a long running parallel query and have time to query SQL monitoring data:

```
create or replace function f1 return number parallel_enable as
begin
  dbms_lock.sleep(1800);
  return 1;
end;
/
```

Then this table:

```
create table t1 as select * from dual connect by level <= 4;
```

And:

```
alter session force parallel query parallel 4;
```

And start this query:

```
select f1 from t1;
```

If you query `GV$SQL_MONITOR`, with some additional columns, you can see it is a parallel query, and the sessions it's spawned, and also find the session that originally started it (QCSID):

```
select sql_exec_start, sql_id, sql_exec_id, sid, px_qcinst_id, px_qcsid from gv$sql_monitor
where status = 'EXECUTING';

SQL_EXEC_START      SQL_ID        SQL_EXEC_ID        SID PX_QCINST_ID   PX_QCSID
------------------- ------------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ----------
2017-09-26 22:20:55 25kj6ftn2vhrn    16777216        270            1        262
2017-09-26 22:20:55 25kj6ftn2vhrn    16777216         20            1        262
2017-09-26 22:20:55 25kj6ftn2vhrn    16777216        262                        
2017-09-26 22:20:55 25kj6ftn2vhrn    16777216        400            1        262
2017-09-26 22:20:55 25kj6ftn2vhrn    16777216        134            1        262
```